# Forfiles command, unknown meaning

Tags: forfiles

Can someone please explain what `-p`, `-s`, `-m`, `/D` and `/C` mean in below?

```dos
forfiles -p "U:\All Portfolio Solutions" -s -m *.* /D -4 /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: Or try `forfiles /?`